# Best approach to null safe AppLocalization strings

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization, dart-null-safety

### Question

I am using `AppLocalizations.of(context).myString` to internationalize strings in my null safe flutter app.

My IDE tells me that `AppLocalizations.of(context)` can return null. What's the best approach to handle this? Is there a way to ensure `AppLocalizations.of(context)` never returns null?

Currently, I am resorting to the following approach:

```dart
AppLocalizations.of(context)?.myString ?? 'Fallback string'
```

### Full Project Code

#### Pubspec.yaml

```yaml
name: Sample Intl Project
description: A sample project
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0-133.2.beta <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
```

#### l10n.yaml

```yaml
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en_US.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
```

#### l10n/app_en_US.arb

```json
{
  "helloWorld": "Hello World!",
  "@helloWorld": {
    "description": "Greeting"
}
```

#### l10n/app_en.arb

```json
{
  "helloWorld": "Hello World!"
}
```

#### main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sample App',
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      home: Home()
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        AppLocalizations.of(context)?.helloWorld ?? 'Hello World!'
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where package does `AppLocalizations` comes from?

Comment: It's auto generated when you add internationalization configuration to a Flutter app. See the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#adding-your-own-localized-messages), specifically steps 6 and 7.

Comment: Could you pleade provide more Code, this message does not occur to me

Comment: Try just `AppLocalizations.of(context).myString`. You need to opt into null safety first by executing the following commands: `flutter channel beta; flutter upgrade` in a terminal.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

add this line in l10n.yaml:

```yaml
nullable-getter: false
```

Comment: Why does this work? What is this supposed to do? Where can we find more info about this?

Comment: I saw this in one of the bloc library [examples](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_todos/l10n.yaml).
But this is the [relevant PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/79263) in the flutter github.

Comment: It makes my app crash, so maybe it was a solution some time ago, but not for `intl 0.17.0`

Comment: @Przemo I am also using version 0.17.0 and there is no problem.

Answer (score 6):

If you are sure, that `AppLocalizations.of(context)` will always return
a valid `AppLocalizations` instance (which is true for your sample application), you can use:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context)!.myString
```

The `!` operator tells Dart, that `AppLocalizations.of(context)` will never return
`null` and acts like a cast from the nullable `AppLocalizations?` to the non-nullable `AppLocalizations`.

Note: If `AppLocalizations.of(context)` returns `null` at runtime, then `AppLocalizations.of(context)!` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 5):

(I'm not allowed to comment so I am answering)

Add key/value

```
nullable-getter: false
```

to `l10n.yaml` (located at the root of the project).

This will automatically do a null check on `AppLocalizations.of(context)`, allowing the programmer to just write `AppLocalizations.of(context).<key>` instead of `AppLocalizations.of(context)!.<key>`.

From [Flutter's documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#configuring-the-l10nyaml-file):

> [no-]nullable-getter
>
> Specifies whether the localizations class getter is nullable.
>
> By default, this value is true so that Localizations.of(context)
> returns a nullable value for backwards compatibility. If this value is
> false, then a null check is performed on the returned value of
> Localizations.of(context), removing the need for null checking in user
> code.

Answer (score 1):

As also said in a comment, I would ask you to share more of your code, your pubpsec your l10n.yaml and anything else relevant as far as you can.

My suggestion until then is to update intl in your dependencies from the latest to:

`intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2`

I assume that nullsafety will not be left to the end devs and it will be standard very soon without having to think about it.

Comment: Thanks, I was already using `intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2`, I have shared my full project code.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, your app always expects `string` value from `AppLocalizations` texts.
I suggest ensuring `string` is null safe, and that should solve your problem.
Here is snippets that you can use.

1. Define a string extension

```
// a string extension
extension MyStringExtentions on String {
  String nullSafeStr() =>
      (this == null || this.isEmpty || this == "null") ? "" : this;
}

// OR a static method
//static String nullSafeStr(String source) => (source == null || source.isEmpty || source == "null") ? "" : source;
```

now you can use either of them, see example using the new extension

```
// .nullSafeStr() becomes available wherever you import the extension method 
AppLocalizations.of(context).helloWorld.nullSafeStr()

// the alternative way is to call the static method  
.nullSafeStr(AppLocalizations.of(context).helloWorld);
```

Comment: Where is the documentation that says using `.translate('key')` is required? In the [official internationalizing Flutter guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#adding-your-own-localized-messages). It does not use `.translate('key')`

Comment: apologies, that was my bad, I copied the snippet from my apps. I have a utility which abstracts `AppLocalizations` usage and I use `.translate('key')` method for all keys.  I'll update my answer

Comment: @AdamGriffiths have already tried my suggestion?

Comment: Yes but it's not a great suggestion. Firstly `AppLocalizations.of(context).helloWorld.nullSafeStr()` has to be turned to `AppLocalizations.of(context)?.helloWorld.nullSafeStr()`. Secondly in the case it is actually null we would return an empty string which would make the UI look weird.