# "AppLocalizations.of(context)!value" make error "Null check operator used on a null value"

Tags: flutter, dart

When I am using AppLocalizations.of(context)!.value in ternary operation in flutter , then it show error "Null check operator used on a null value".

> Here is an example of usage that makes error:

```
isLoading ? AppLocalizations.of(context)!.loading : AppLocalizations.of(context)!.value
```

In this code show error Null check operator used on a null value

```
isLoading ? Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.orderIsBeingSending) : Text("${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.orderId} : ${orderSummary.orderResponse?.no.toString()}");
```

Debug output:
[image: Debug output]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657443/best-approach-to-null-safe-applocalization-strings

Comment: Please try to make your uestion more readable. Espacially your code highlighting. See this post to learn the basics of posting your code to StackOverflow: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/407041

Answer (score 0):

add this line in l10n.yaml:

```
nullable-getter: false
```

Comment: No , It is not working, Same error.